# Custom JodaTime serialization class returns huge object

Tags: java, serialization, jodatime

I need to serialize Joda DateTime to JSON as single string. I use implementation of JsonSerializer which suppose to generate string but I am getting object with a lot of properties:

```
"metrics":{"startTimestamp":{"year":2014,"dayOfMonth":11,"dayOfWeek":2,"era":1,"dayOfYear":315,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfCentury":14,"monthOfYear":11,"weekOfWeekyear":46,"millisOfSecond":505,"millisOfDay":36348505,"secondOfMinute":48,"secondOfDay":36348,"minuteOfHour":5,.......... etc
```

But I need something string like `dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS`. How to do that?

**CustomDateSerializer**

```
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {
    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(formatter.print(value));
//        System.out.println(formatter.print(value));
    }
    @Override
    public Class<DateTime> handledType() {
        return DateTime.class;
    }
}
```

**Metrics**

```
    import app.service.CustomDateSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

public class Metrics {
//    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    DateTime startTimestamp;
//    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
    DateTime endTimestamp;
    Period period;
    @JsonIgnore
    PeriodFormatter periodFormatter;

    public Metrics() {

    }
    public DateTime getStartTimestamp() {
        return startTimestamp;
    }

    public void setStartTimestamp(DateTime startTimestamp) {
        this.startTimestamp = startTimestamp;
    }

    public DateTime getEndTimestamp() {
        return endTimestamp;
    }

    public void setEndTimestamp(DateTime endTimestamp) {
        this.endTimestamp = endTimestamp;
    }

    public Period getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }
    public void setPeriod() {
        this.period = new Period(this.startTimestamp, this.endTimestamp);
    }
    public void setPeriod(Period period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public PeriodFormatter getPeriodFormatter() {
        return periodFormatter;
    }

    public void setPeriodFormatter(PeriodFormatter periodFormatter) {
        this.periodFormatter = periodFormatter;
    }
   @Override
   public String toString(){
       this.periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                .printZeroAlways()
                .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
                .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
                .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
                .appendSeconds().appendSeparator(".")
                .appendMillis3Digit()
                .toFormatter();
       return "Started: " + this.startTimestamp.toString() + "\\n" + "Ended:   " + this.endTimestamp.toString() + "\\n" + "Response took: " + periodFormatter.print(period)+ "";
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

`System.out.println(formatter.print(value))` in `CustomDateSerializer` actually prints correct string but for some reason it failed to pass it to serializer I assume.....

**UPDATE2**

**Controller**

```
public @ResponseBody XmlResponse getGUID( @RequestParam(/*...*/) String environmentParam) {
//.... XmlResponse xmlResponse = ..........
return xmlResponse;
}
```

**XmlResponse class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class XmlResponse {
    String xmlResponseBody;
    @JsonIgnore
    Metrics metrics;
    Boolean error;

    public XmlResponse() {
    }

    public XmlResponse(String xmlResponseBody, Metrics metrics, Boolean error) {
        this.xmlResponseBody = xmlResponseBody;
        this.metrics = metrics;
        this.error = error;
    }

    public String getXmlResponseBody() {
        return xmlResponseBody;
    }

    public void setXmlResponseBody(String xmlResponseBody) {
        this.xmlResponseBody = xmlResponseBody;
    }
    @JsonProperty("metrics")
    public Metrics getMetrics() {
        return metrics;
    }

    public void setMetrics(Metrics metrics) {
        this.metrics = metrics;
    }

    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String out = "";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
//            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
//            mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
             out = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "{}";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE3**

uncommenting `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)` does not change the result

Comment: Your code appears to give the expected output for me with `ObjectMapper#writeValue`. How exactly do you perform serialization?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a mix of Jackson 1.x (`org.codehaus.jackson`) and Jackson 2.x (`com.fasterxml.jackson`). While their APIs are very similar, annotations by Jackson 1.x have no effect for Jackson 2.x and vice versa (unless you use [jackson-legacy-introspector](https://github.com/Laures/jackson-legacy-introspector)).

Making sure that you use the same Jackson version everywhere should help with your problem.
You can get some more information there: [Upgrading Jackson 1.9 to 2.0](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonUpgradeFrom19To20).